# Finding $P(X_{1} = 1 \mid X_{1} + X_{2} + \cdots + X_{n} = m)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have sequence of random variables $\{X_{i}\}$ This is a sequence of Bernoulli trials. Each $X_{i} = 1$ with probability $p$ with $0$ with probability $1-p$. Find  $P(X_{1} = 1 \mid X_{1} + X_{2} + \cdots + X_{n} = m)$.

I used conditional probability:

$$\frac{P(X_{1} = 1, X_{1} + \cdots + X_{n} = m)}{P(X_{1} + \cdots + X_{n} =m )} = \frac{P(X_{1} = 1) P(X_{2} + \cdots + X_{n} = m - 1) }{{n\choose m} p^{m}(1 - p)^{n - m}} $$

$$= \frac{p \cdot {n-1\choose m-1} p^{m-1} (1 - p)^{n - (m - 1)}}{{n\choose m} p^{m} (1-p)^{n-m}} $$

I'm not sure how to compute the top. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

If the $X_i$ are independent then the numerator is $$P(X_{1} = 1, X_{2} + \cdots + X_{n} = m-1)=P(X_{1} = 1)\,P(X_{2} + \cdots + X_{n} = m-1)$$ which you can state in the same binomial way

Rather more directly, given $m$ of the $n$ $X_i$s are $1$ then by symmetry the conditional probability that $X_1=1$ is $\dfrac m n$

Comment: I think $m/n$ is right, but how come what I wrote in the original post doesn't simplify to that?

Comment: You wrote $\frac{p \cdot {n-1\choose m-1} p^{m-1} (1 - p)^{n - (m - 1)}}{{n\choose m} p^{m} (1-p)^{n-m}}$ when you should have written $\frac{p \cdot {n-1\choose m-1} p^{m-1} (1 - p)^{(n-1) - (m - 1)}}{{n\choose m} p^{m} (1-p)^{n-m}}$.  You can then simplify to $\frac{{n-1\choose m-1}}{{n\choose m}} =\frac{\frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!(n-m)!}}{\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}} = \frac{m}{n}$